# Quit VLC if already running

Tags: python, wxpython, vlc

I am having a weird problem with VLC in Python. Using the following things.

```
import vlc

self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
self.List = self.Instance.media_list_new()
self.Player_d = self.Instance.media_list_player_new()
```

I am using `self.List.add_media(address of video)` to populate the media list.

Then `self.Player_d.set_media_list(self.List)`
and  `self.Player_d.play()`

The problem is that VLC starts in a weird (YUV something) window, without any controls. Then freezes after playing the list. I have to use Task Manager to shut it down.

Can anybody point out the problem? I want to play the VLC with all controls.

Secondly, is there anyway of checking if VLC is already running, if running, then to quit and start a new instance of VLC.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about passing `'--play-and-exit'` to `vlc.Instance()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything about wxPython in your question, but if you're using it with the vlc module, then that could be your problem. I'm guessing they don't play nicely together. You probably need to run all the vlc stuff in a separate thread rather than in wx's main loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike. I am making the playlist (self.List) from the files collected in the wx.ListBox. I runs creates the playlist and runs the plays all the tracks (without any controls i-e Pause, Stop, etc) in YUV window but then it freezes.